# Bind items collection in ListView, but show their child collections rather than the main items themselves

Tags: c#, wpf

My program contains an `ObservableCollection` of `MapFiles`, which I bind to in various ListViews. Some `MapFiles` contain lists of `TagItems` however, and in my latest window I want the ListView to show all the `TagItems` within all relevant `MapFiles` at the same time.

I know I can do this by manually adding `Items` to the ListView, but then I'd also need to maintain this if `TagItems` were added or deleted, and so I'd really like to set this up using `ItemsSource`.

So basically I want to bind to all my `MapFiles`, but instead of showing the `MapItems` themselves in the ListView I want to show their `TagItems`, if they have any. I'm sure this must be possible, - does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to show tagitems per mapitem then you can use the fullname.. like as

```
listview.itemssource = mapitem.tagitem;
```

in xaml

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding MapItem.TagItem}" />
```

this will show only tagitems in list.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that will just show the TagItems from a single MapItem? I want to show all TagItems from all MapItems in the same ListView, if possible.